# How to save more than 8000 characters in a SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, max, varchar

I have one column AgentName in a table Test which contains more characters. I am getting differences in length as shown below.

If you see "C" , I have copied the output of @TMP and doing DataLength where I think should get the same as B.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally when you copy value from Result grid, data will be retrieved as per your Query options setting in SSMS ( Query -> Query Options -> Results -> Grid -> Max characters retrieved)

As below result : defaulted to 65535 and data copied from result grid was only of length 65535 [image: Defaulted to 65535]

[image: Query Result :]

After when you update the options value for grid :
[image: Query result]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's because the SQL Server Management Studio is not rendering the whole length, so you are copping less details. If you want to get the whole text cast it as `XML`.

Instead `SELECT @TMP` do:

```
SELECT CAST(@TMP AS XML)
```

then open the value, copy it and detect its length.

Comment: A tiny add-on: It might be necessary, to right-click the query and set the option for XML in grid to "unlimited"...

Answer (score 1):

You can define the column as `VARCHAR(MAX)`, which supports more than 8000 characters.

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
   B VARCHAR(MAX),
   C VARCHAR(MAX)
)
```